# Spring Security in a microservices architecture

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a microservices architecture, and i want to secure the REST API of each microservice which is developed in spring boot, should i use spring security in each one? I have an auth service, which will be the authenticator and authorizator and the other microservices will use their services to validate token, authorization? Is this correct? Any help with the code?

Answer (score 3):

The approach I take in my projects is to have a gateway application `netflix-zuul` (not actively developed anymore but more mature) or `spring-cloud-gateway` (developed by the spring team and a successor to `zuul`, but still has some quirks as a rather fresh project. Recommended for new apps)

The gateway would then be the only service that is directly exposed to the user while all of the other services (auth, business logic, etc) would be placed in a DMZ and unreachable from the outside of your network.

[image: image credit: Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/architecture/microservices/images/gateway.png)]

If you follow the said architecture, you would only need to implement security in the gateway service and, assuming the implementation and the network setup is correct, you would not need to worry about the security inside the other services.

In practice, I still keep the toked parsing modules in each service as the access token carries user-identifying information that is used in my business logic. This, however, is used for data transportation and not for security purposes.

The gateway has to be configured (plenty of guides and samples are available online for either of the two) to be aware of each of your services or you might want to include a `service registry` (such as `netflix-eureka`) to keep track of all of your services and instances.

A service registry is a lightweight service that would provide your gateway service with dynamic aliases for each service and save you all the set-up hassle when you are scaling your infrastructure beyond a single PM (physical machine) and provide load balancing for you at little to no additional development cost

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to secure endpoints of all services, the best approach is to implement Spring Security in all applications. You can have one centralized application that performs authentication and authorization (let's say, auth-service). Other services would use an authentication manager that would point to remote token service (present in your auth-service). With this in place, you can define security protection rules for various endpoints in each application, something like this:

```
<sec:filter-security-metadata-source id="securityMetadataSource"
                                     request-matcher="ant"
                                     use-expressions="true">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated() and hasRole('ADMIN')"/>
```

In the above example, we've declared a rule that all endpoints that starts with `/admin/**` should be authenticated and should have role `ADMIN`.

Depending on your use case, you can configure that each services should also need to authenticate themselves. This means you can secure your intra-service communication as well.

Comment: That's exactly the approach I'm looking for. So, could you help me with some code or example for the spring security structure. I am using an OAuth2 provider for the authentication. The XML you provide me can be used through configure() method right? My other doubt is: How do I tell the other services that should point to my auth service?. Thanks.

Comment: I want my microservices to authenticate and authorize against the auth service. All this through Spring Security, is this possible?

Comment: Spring provides `OAuth2AuthenticationManager` class in it we can configure `RemoteTokenServices`. Please note that in current Spring Security release, they have deprecated entire `org.springframework.security.oauth2` package and they are not going to provide any implementation for authorization server.

Comment: Yes, I know about that, so, it's possible to achieve this with the new Spring Security release?

Comment: I'm not sure as we haven't started migrating our existing auth server.